# How should I structure account creation with PayPal?

Tags: php, paypal

I am implementing PayPal HTML buttons on my website, and I want to know what would be the best practice for registering customers to use my website. Should I have users fill out information before they pay and validate their accounts once a payment is made? Or should I have them create an account after a payment is verified? Also, at what stage should I input any associated data from the customers into my database? Thank you for any tips/suggestions!

Edit: My website is an online software website where users will pay a monthly fee to have log in and software access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, payment should always be the last action of the user cause if anything else goes wrong, you don't want to have to undo the payment. So let the user navigate your website anonymously if he wants. Then, when he wants to buy something, ask him to log (if he already has an account) or register (if he does not have the account), and then he can process the payment on paypal once he is authenticated.
You will send his information to the database when he submits his account registration. If his submissions fails for some reason (missing field or whatever), he will have to do again until it works.

Not sure that answers your question. Of course, that seems the most logical way to me, but there might be some cases where you want to do things differently (which I do not see right now)

Comment: I appreciate the response. Can you read my edit and let my know if you would add/change anything about your response?

Comment: You cannot allow him to log in only if he already subscribed (cause he cannot subscribe if he cannot log in). Let him log in and see his account. Then subscribe to have access to the software, in my opinion